# Java calls to methods are not working

Tags: java

I'm taking my first Java class and have error in printing out more lines than required

So I assume the program is repeating instead of exit and going down to next method. Not certain how to correct this repeat, tried to change first `return -1;` with no correction.

Assignment asks "Define stubs for the methods called by the below main()." and to print these 4 lines:

```
FIXME: Finish getUserNum()
FIXME: Finish getUserNum()
FIXME: Finish computeAvg()
Avg: -1
```

I have Print out of:

```
FIXME: Finish getUserNum()
FIXME: Finish getUserNum()
FIXME: Finish getUserNum()
FIXME: Finish getUserNum()
FIXME: Finish computeAvg()
Avg: -1
```

Here is my attempt w/ my code noted:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class MthdStubsStatistics {

   /* Your solution goes here  */
   public static Integer getUserNum() {
      System.out.println("FIXME: Finish getUserNum()");
      System.out.println("FIXME: Finish getUserNum()");
      return -1;
   }   

   public static Integer computeAvg(int userNum1, int userNum2){
      System.out.println("FIXME: Finish computeAvg()"); 
      return -1;
   }/* ^ Your solution goes here ^  */


   public static void main() {
      int userNum1 = 0;
      int userNum2 = 0;
      int avgResult = 0;

      userNum1 = getUserNum();
      userNum2 = getUserNum();

      avgResult = computeAvg(userNum1, userNum2);

      System.out.println("Avg: " + avgResult);

      return;
   }
}
```

Comment: "I am very open to suggestions on how to improve how I ask a question" - read [ask]

Comment: Why do you call `System.out.println("FIXME: Finish getUserNum()");` inside `getUserNum()` twice? If you call that method twice and each call will in turn call the print statement twice you'll get 4 lines (2 x 2).

Comment: just remove the second System.out.println("FIXME: Finish getUserNum()"); inside getUserNum()

Comment: the requirement was to print it twice so I wrote it twice. I don't see how it is called twice ... I just removed it and now 'FIXME: Finish computeAvg()' is printing twice and FIXME: Finish getUserNum()' once... I don't see the mistake yet...

Comment: @L.Lab1 In `main` you call `getUserNum()` twice. Each execution of `getUserNum` prints the line twice. 2x2 = 4.

Comment: @JohnnyMopp I see, I thought the call had to be in () - so it can be anywhere in the main statement?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You're making two calls to `getUserNum` and one call to `computeAvg`.